# Input autocomplete in React: How do you update a mapped array in the UI?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-query

I'm writing an address autocomplete field that uses the Google Places autocomplete API.

I'm using React Query to fetch the data as the user types, and showing a `<datalist>` inside which I'm mapping over the array and outputting `<options>` when the array of predictions comes in.

All of that works, but the dropdown containing the fetched options doesn't show in the UI unless I click out of the browser window and back into the address field.

Relevant code:

```
const [placeData, placeIsLoading, placeIsSuccess, placeIsError, placeError] = useFetchPlacesAutocomplete(address)


const [address, setAddress] = useState()
const [addressAutocomplete, setAddressAutocomplete] = useState(false)

<FormControl id="address" position="relative">
                        <FormLabel htmlFor="address">Address</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            w="20rem"
                            mb={8}
                            value={address}
                            variant={addressAutocomplete ? "flushed" : "outline"}
                            list="predictions"
                            onChange={e => {
                                setAddress(e.target.value)
                                handleAutocomplete(e)
                            }}
                        />
                        {addressAutocomplete && placeIsSuccess &&
                            <datalist id="predictions">
                                {placeIsSuccess &&  placeData.predictions.map(i => (
                                    <option
                                        key={i.description}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            setAddress(i.description)
                                            setAddressAutocomplete(false)
                                        }}
                                        value={i.description}
                                    />

                                ))}

                            </datalist>
                        }


                    </FormControl>
```

I think the main question is, why is the `placeData` variable updating as the user types, but the result of mapping over that array isn't showing up in the UI in real time?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Additional info. I believe I know why it's not updating - React is receiving `placeData` as an array, but the state isn't considered updated if the contents of that array changes, so the component won't re-render. So I think the solution is to force a re-render when input field changes, but I don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: If you update some state a re-render happens. So you can trigger a re-render by updating some state. But I would first recommend checking your conditions `addressAutocomplete && placeIsSuccess` and if that actually works. Does the previous condition evaluate to `true`? Also what does `placeData.predictions` look like?

Comment: impossible to tell without knowing what `useFetchPlacesAutocomplete` does. is the address part of the queryKey?

Comment: @TkDodo I added the address to the queryKey and it worked, that was it. It was previously just a string.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (or at least my solution) was to pass the input from the address state as the queryKey to generate a new query for each keystroke. Previously the queryKey was just a string.